# Find all equilibrium values of the given system of differential equations:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all equilibrium values of the given system of differential equations:

a. $$\frac{dx}{dt}=x-x^2-2xy$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2y-2y^2-3xy$$

b. $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\beta xy+ \upsilon$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\beta xy-\gamma y$$

My attempt: 
So equilibrium values are when the derivatives = 0

a. $$\frac{dx}{dt}=0=x-x^2-2xy$$
$$0=x(1-x-2y)$$
so $x=0$ or $(1-x-2y)=0$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=0=2y-2y^2-3xy$$
$$=y(2-2y-3x)$$

so $y=0$ or $(2-2y-3x)=0$

The possibilities are
$$x=0;y=0$$

$$x=0;y=1$$
$0=(2-2y-3x)=2-2y$

$2=2y$

$y=1$

$$x=2/3;y=0$$
$0=(2-2y-3x)$

$0=2-3x$

$x=2/3$

$$x=3/4;y=1/8$$

$(1-x-2y)=0$

$x=1-2y$

$(2-2y-3x)=0$

$2-2y-3(1-2y)=0$

$2-2y-1-6y=0$

$1-8y=0$

$y=1/8$

$x=1-2/8$

$x=6/8=3/4$

But the book only agrees with me on the first 2 answers, so I'm not sure where I made my mistake.

b. $$\frac{dx}{dt}=0=-\beta xy+ \upsilon$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=0=\beta xy-\gamma y$$
$$0=y(\beta x - \gamma)$$

so $0=-\beta xy+ \upsilon$ and $y=0$ or $(\beta x - \gamma)=0$

$$x=???;y=0$$

$0=-\beta xy+ \upsilon$

$0=\upsilon$

But $\upsilon$ is not a variable, so would I just say if $\upsilon=0$ then y=o and all x are solutions?

$$x=\frac{\gamma}{\beta};y=\frac{\upsilon}{\gamma}$$

$(\beta x - \gamma)=0$

$\beta x=\gamma$

$x=\frac{\gamma}{\beta}$

$0=-\beta xy+ \upsilon$

$0=-\gamma y+ \upsilon$

$\gamma y=upsilon$

$y=\frac{\upsilon}{\gamma}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. From your conditions you have 4 systems:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= 0,\\
y &= 0,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= 0,\\
2-2y-3x &= 0,
\end{aligned}
\right.
\quad
\Longrightarrow
\quad
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= 0,\\
y &= 1,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
1-x-2y &= 0,\\
y &= 0,
\end{aligned}
\right.
\quad
\Longrightarrow
\quad
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= 1,\\
y &= 0,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
1-x-2y &= 0,\\
2-2y-3x &= 0,
\end{aligned}
\right.
\quad
\Longrightarrow
\quad
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= \frac{1}{2},\\
y &= \frac{1}{4}.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

b. You are correct in both cases $v=0$ and $v \neq 0$.